# How to switch between panes in modern Windows Terminal like tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, windows-terminal

ITNOA

If I use `ctrl+shift+p`, I can see some shortcut for creating panes in [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal), for example `alt+shift+-` is for creating horizontal pane and `alt+shift+plus` is for creating vertical panes.

But I don't find anything for switching between panes after creation without mouse clicking in command palette.

**Note**: I like to switch between panes like [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) with some shortcuts similar to `tmux` `ctrl+b+left/right` **How to doing that?**

My question is posted on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69577188/1539100) before, and close for off-topic question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After I searching in Bing, I found [Panes in Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/panes#:%7E:text=1%20Creating%20a%20new%20pane.%20You%20can%20either,pane%20depending%20on%20your%20custom%20key%20bindings.%20) manual, and this manual has one section that name is [Switching between panes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/panes#switching-between-panes). as you can see in this manual, for switching between panes you have to using `alt+down/up/left/right` (down/up/left/right are arrow keys in keyboard)

If you want change these commands like [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) you can add below configs in `settings.json` (found with `ctrl+,` and click Open JSON file)

```json
{ "command": { "action": "moveFocus", "direction": "down" }, "keys": "ctrl+b+down" },
{ "command": { "action": "moveFocus", "direction": "left" }, "keys": "ctrl+b+left" },
{ "command": { "action": "moveFocus", "direction": "right" }, "keys": "ctrl+b+right" },
{ "command": { "action": "moveFocus", "direction": "up" }, "keys": "ctrl+b+up" },
{ "command": { "action": "moveFocus", "direction": "previous" } },
{ "command": { "action": "moveFocus", "direction": "previousInOrder" } },
{ "command": { "action": "moveFocus", "direction": "nextInOrder" } }
```

My answer is posted on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69577189/1539100) before, and close my question for off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

**Move focus** is the command of navigation between panes within a tab.

Default shortcut is <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>:

- <kbd>Alt+↑</kbd> pane **Up**
- <kbd>Alt+→</kbd> pane **Right**
- <kbd>Alt+↓</kbd> pane **Down**
- <kbd>Alt+←</kbd> pane **Left**

For multiple movements hold key <kbd>ALT</kbd> and pres several times the <kbd>arrow key</kbd> to move pane by pane in that direction.